# A simple script with timeout value dependent on value in element's attribute - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I am trying to run a script which removes an element from DOM after a declared number of seconds.

The script should service multiple elements which disappear after a declared time.

The element:

```
<div class="communique-warning data-closein="2">
You forgot to declare your country!
</div>
<div class="communique-info data-closein="5">
Your action was completed successfully!
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$('[data-closein]').each(function() {
    var after = $(this).data("closein") + '000';
    console.log('Time to delete: ' + after);

setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    console.log('rolled up');
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('removed!');
}, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
});
```

### problems:

With the above code I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined` error.

1. It seems that the `this` context doesnt work inside the setTimeout. What is the proper syntax to do that?
2. Can I put variable `after` in place of the 3000 miliseconds value of the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: you can create a variable _this and assign it like
var _this = this; and use _this inside your setTimeout function and you cant put variable in place of millisecond parameter

Answer (score 0):

well `$(this)` inside the function that `setTimeout` calls, refers to that function. You can simply asign `$(this)` before that function to a variable and then use that inside the function that `setTimeout` calls:

```
$('[data-closein]').each(function() {
    var after = $(this).data("closein") + '000';
    console.log('Time to delete: ' + after);
    vat $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.fadeOut('fast');
    console.log('rolled up');
    $this.remove();
    console.log('removed!');
}, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the this in setTimeout. "this" in setTimeout is different from where you have it initially on the each function. To fix it you need to save this or bind it to the function you passed to setTimeout..

```
$('[data-closein]').each(function() {
    var after = $(this).data("closein") + '000';
    console.log('Time to delete: ' + after);
    var $dataCloseIn = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $dataCloseIn.fadeOut('fast');
        console.log('rolled up');
        $dataCloseIn$.remove();
        console.log('removed!');
    }, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds

    /* or
    var removeDataCloseIn = function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        console.log('rolled up');
        $(this).remove();
        console.log('removed!');
    }.bind(this);
    setTimeout(removeDataCloseIn,3000);
    */
 });
```

Find out more here https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes

Comment: It works! Thank you
Still... any way to pass the value from `data-closein` attribute, so that  any element would disappear in its own time?

Comment: you should be able to do it via data-closein attribute when you create the element and retrieve that from within the each function.

```var after = parseInt($(this).attr('data-closein'));
//then
setTimeout( function..., after);```